# Confusion about nginx cache status hit after stale when upstream is down

Tags: nginx

My upstream server is down, nginx is configured to serve stale content .. so after cache expires ...
In the first request we see the response header for $upstream_cache_status as STALE.
However the next request .. we see a response of HIT.

I though that all requests will be STALE since the upstream server is down.
AM I correct or am I missing something ...

Here is my config

```
         add_header 'Cache-Control' "no-cache";
         proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
         proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
         proxy_cache aaa_cache;

         proxy_cache_lock on;
         proxy_cache_lock_timeout 60s;
         proxy_cache_lock_age 15s;
         proxy_cache_revalidate on;
         add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
         proxy_cache_valid 200 3m;
         proxy_cache_valid any 30s;
         proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
         proxy_cache_background_update on;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The cache expiration is calculated separately for each cached element. Let's look at an example sequence of events:

```
00:00:00 GET /                 - MISS  -> cached, TTL 3m, expires at 00:03:00
00:00:30 GET /example          - MISS  -> cached, TTL 3m, expires at 00:03:30
00:02:00 upstream taken down
00:02:10 GET /                 - HIT   -> cached entry still valid
00:03:10 GET /                 - STALE -> cached entry stale
00:03:20 GET /example          - HIT   -> cached entry still valid
00:03:40 GET /example          - STALE -> cached entry stale
```

So, cache entry status is HIT until the TTL for that entry expires.

Comment: What about 00:03:20  GET /  I expect another STALE , but I see a HIT ...is that correct. I expect a STALE because my upstream is still down.

Comment: The `/example` entry was fetched at 00:00:30, and is valid for 3 minutes, that is, until `00:03:30`. So, when it is fetched at `00:03:20`, it is still valid, therefore it is `HIT`.

Comment: Yes you are correct .. in my situation ... if I try   GET /example at 00:03:42  . I get a HIT.  I though this should ought to be a STALE.